# Is there a way to set my field values in MongoDB query dynamic?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am running a MongoDB query and trying to change the way my output is structured. Currently it looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    qClass: [
      {
        cat: 'Servers',
        class: 'High Impact Maintenance',
        total: 1
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.TrafficShapers',
        class: 'Maintenance',
        total: 16
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.Hop',
        class: 'Core Failure',
        total: 2
      },
      {
        cat: 'Office.MFD',
        class: 'Failure',
        total: 4
      },
      {
        cat: 'Office.Printers',
        class: 'Maintenance',
        total: 36
      },
      {
        cat: 'Office.MFD',
        class: 'Maintenance',
        total: 880
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.TrafficShapers',
        class: 'Failure',
        total: 47
      },
      {
        cat: 'Servers',
        class: 'Core Maintenance',
        total: 1
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.Switches',
        class: 'Failure',
        total: 5
      },
      {
        cat: 'Servers',
        class: 'Performance',
        total: 21
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.Switches',
        class: 'High Impact Failure',
        total: 4
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.Firewall',
        class: 'Core Failure',
        total: 2
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.Router',
        class: 'Failure',
        total: 53
      },
      {
        cat: 'Servers',
        class: 'High Impact Failure',
        total: 3
      },
      {
        cat: 'Office.Printers',
        class: 'Performance',
        total: 1
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.TrafficShapers',
        class: 'Performance',
        total: 3
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.Switches',
        class: 'Maintenance',
        total: 1
      },
      {
        cat: 'Servers',
        class: 'Failure',
        total: 60
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.Router',
        class: 'Performance',
        total: 67
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.Router',
        class: 'High Impact Failure',
        total: 39
      },
      {
        cat: 'Office.MFD',
        class: 'Performance',
        total: 5
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.TrafficShapers',
        class: 'High Impact Failure',
        total: 593
      },
      {
        cat: 'Network.Router',
        class: 'Maintenance',
        total: 78
      },
      {
        cat: 'Office.Printers',
        class: 'High Impact Failure',
        total: 2
      },
      {
        cat: 'Office.Printers',
        class: 'Failure',
        total: 1
      },
      {
        cat: 'Office.MFD',
        class: 'Critical Failure',
        total: 48
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I hoped to have it structured as follows:

```
{
    cat: 'Servers',
    High Impact Maintenance: 1,
    Performance: 24,
   Total: 25
}
```

So basically,  all info on cat (category ) in the same array and have the field name dynamic to the class. Below is the query that I am using for this:

```
db.full_ticket_lists.aggregate(
  {
    
    $facet: {
            qClass: [
          {$match : {"device":{$ne:null},"status":"Open","ticket_class":{$ne:''}}},
          {$lookup: { from: "devices", localField: "device",  foreignField: "_id", as: "device_link"},},
          {$lookup: { from: "device_categories", localField: "device_link.device_category",  foreignField: "_id", as: "category_link"},},
          {$unwind: "$category_link"},
          {$group : {
                      _id:{"class_name":"$ticket_class", "cat_name":"$category_link.name"}, 
                      count: {$sum:1}
          },},
          {$project:{_id:0,cat:"$_id.cat_name", class:"$_id.class_name",total:"$count"}}
      ],
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: where is other collections? or you just want to do in that your provided first json? so i have prepared like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/vyGaHfXWJ0z is this helpful?

Comment: @turivishal That is very helpful thanks a lot, it solved my issue! I am getting a bit lost in the following section, mind explaining to me what it does? 

{
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            $arrayToObject: "$classes"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },

Answer (score 0):

Take a look step by step, Focusing on your expected result,

```
{
  "cat": 'Servers',
  "High Impact Maintenance": 1,
  "Performance": 24,
  "Total": 25
}
```

- `$unwind` `qClass` because its an array and we need each object in below $group part
- `$group` by `cat` and
- create `classes` to push `class` as a k(key) and `total` as a v(value)
- create `total` to push sum of all `total`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$qClass"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$qClass.cat",
      cat: {
        $first: "$qClass.cat"
      },
      classes: {
        $push: {
          k: "$qClass.class",
          v: "$qClass.total"
        }
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$qClass.total"
      }
    }
  },
```

- [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) will replace the root with new array
- [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) will merge two objects first `$$ROOT` and second `$classes` that is converted to object from array
- [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) will convert `classes` array to an object, it will convert k(key) and v(value) to an object

```
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            $arrayToObject: "$classes"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$project` will hide not needed fields *(0 = hide, 1 = show)* so here `_id` and `classes` are hidden both are no longer needed

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      classes: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vyGaHfXWJ0z